# ANT Table with dropdown

Tags: reactjs

I have a 3 select inside a table inside a form. Im calling the api to populate this one select on the componentdidmount. the next one gets populated depending on the value selected in the first one. and the last one gets populated depending on the value selected in the second one. How can I do this. Im using a editable table component from ANT design.

Im using axios for the api.

```
apiSelect(){
    axios
    .get(`http://10.42.0.108:8000/asset_request/required_type_dropdown?id=${this.columns.requesttype}`)
    .then(response=>response.data)
    .then(data=>{this.setState({request_type:data.request_type_list})
                this.setState({loading:false});
              })
    .catch(error => {console.log(error);})
  }
```

This is the full code. I modified the original ant file. But Im still only a noob on reactjs so haven't got the entire hang of it yet. Please help guys.

```
    const required_type = {"name":"select"};
    const asset_type = {"name":"select"};
    const EditableContext = React.createContext();
    const { Option } = Select;
    const EditableRow = ({ form, index, ...props }) => (
      <EditableContext.Provider value={form}>
        <tr {...props} />
      </EditableContext.Provider>
    );

    const EditableFormRow = Form.create()(EditableRow);

    class EditableCell extends React.Component {
      state = {
        editing: false,
      };

      toggleEdit = () => {
        const editing = !this.state.editing;
        this.setState({ editing }, () => {
          if (editing) {
            this.input.focus();
          }
        });
      };

      save = e => {
        const { record, handleSave } = this.props;
        this.form.validateFields((error, values) => {
          if (error && error[e.currentTarget.id]) {
            return;
          }
          this.toggleEdit();
          handleSave({ ...record, ...values });
        });
      };

      renderCell = form => {
        this.form = form;
        const { children, dataIndex, record, title } = this.props;
        const { editing } = this.state;
        return editing ? (
          <Form.Item style={{ margin: 0 }}>
            {form.getFieldDecorator(dataIndex, {
              rules: [
                {
                  required: true,
                  message: `${title} is required`,
                },
              ],
              initialValue: record[dataIndex],
            })(<Input ref={node => (this.input = node)} onPressEnter={this.save} onBlur={this.save} />)}
          </Form.Item>
        ) : (
          <div
            className="editable-cell-value-wrap"
            style={{ paddingRight: 24 }}
            onClick={this.toggleEdit}
          >
            {children}
          </div>
        );
      };

      render() {
        const {
          editable,
          dataIndex,
          title,
          record,
          index,
          handleSave,
          children,
          ...restProps
        } = this.props;
        return (
          <td {...restProps}>
            {editable ? (
              <EditableContext.Consumer>{this.renderCell}</EditableContext.Consumer>
            ) : (
              children
            )}
          </td>
        );
      }
    }

    export default class EditableTable extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.columns = [
          {
            title: 'Request Type',
            dataIndex: 'requesttype',
            align:'center',
            //width: '5%',
            render: (select, record) =>
              this.state.dataSource.length >= 1 ? (
                            <Select defaultValue='Select' name='requestType'>
                                {this.props.requesttypedrop.map(person => (
                                    <Option value={person.name} label={person.name} key={person.name}>
                                      {person.name}
                                    </Option>
                                 ))}
                            </Select>
              ) : null,
          },
          {
            title: 'Required Type',
            dataIndex: 'requiredtype',
            align:'center',
            //width: '5%',
            render: (select, record) =>
              this.state.dataSource.length >= 1 ? (
                            <Select defaultValue='Select' name='requiredType'>
                            {/* {required_type.map(person => (
                                    <Option value={person.name} label={person.name} key={person.name}>
                                      {person.name}
                                    </Option>
                                 ))} */}
                            </Select>
              ) : null,
          },
          {
            title: 'Asset Type',
            dataIndex: 'assettype',
            align:'center',
            //width: '5%',
            render: (select, record) =>
              this.state.dataSource.length >= 1 ? (
                            <Select defaultValue='Select' name='assetType'>
                            {/* {asset_type.map(person => (
                                    <Option value={person.name} label={person.name} key={person.name}>
                                      {person.name}
                                    </Option>
                                 ))} */}
                            </Select>
              ) : null,
          },
          {
            title: 'Operation',
            dataIndex: 'operation',
            align:'center',
            render: (text, record) =>
              this.state.dataSource.length >= 1 ? (
                <Popconfirm title="Sure to delete?" onConfirm={() => this.handleDelete(record.key)}>
                  <a href="javascript:;"><Icon style={{color:'#282c34'}} type="delete" theme="filled" /></a>
                </Popconfirm>
              ) : null,
          },
        ];

        this.state = {
          dataSource: [
            {
              key: '0',

            }

          ],
          count: 1,
        };
      }


      handleDelete = key => {
        const dataSource = [...this.state.dataSource];
        this.setState({ dataSource: dataSource.filter(item => item.key !== key) });
      };

      handleAdd = () => {
        const { count, dataSource } = this.state;
        const newData = {
          key: count,

        };
        this.setState({
          dataSource: [...dataSource, newData],
          count: count + 1,
        });
      };

      handleSave = row => {
        const newData = [...this.state.dataSource];
        const index = newData.findIndex(item => row.key === item.key);
        const item = newData[index];
        newData.splice(index, 1, {
          ...item,
          ...row,
        });
        this.setState({ dataSource: newData });
      };

      render() {
        const { dataSource } = this.state;
        const components = {
          body: {
            row: EditableFormRow,
            cell: EditableCell,
          },
        };
        const columns = this.columns.map(col => {
          if (!col.editable) {
            return col;
          }
          return {
            ...col,
            onCell: record => ({
              record,
              editable: col.editable,
              dataIndex: col.dataIndex,
              title: col.title,
              handleSave: this.handleSave,
            }),
          };
        });
        return (
          <div>
            <Table
              components={components}
              rowClassName={() => 'editable-row'}
              bordered
              dataSource={dataSource}
              columns={columns}
              style={{overflowX:"scroll"}}
            />
            <Button onClick={this.handleAdd} style={{ marginTop: 16,float: 'right' }}>
              Add a row
            </Button>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this three keys to your state

```
this.state = {
      select1: true
      select2: true
      select3: true
    };
```

For three select boxes use disabled attribute and set it to true like this..
Ex:

```
 <Select disabled={this.state.select1}></Select>
```

Once you get data from backend, activate the first select in your code

```
this.setState({request_type:data.request_type_list
                loading:false
                select1:false
             });
```

For select box1 in your form, As it becomes false it gets activated. Add event handler to the same select box tag. If anything selected in select box then set state for second select box as false inside event handler which gonna activate second select box. 
Repeat the same for third